# Any dedicated servers that serve up JSON?

Tags: ajax, json, jsonp

I'm looking to retrieve json from a dedicated server. It will be used to verify client to server communications in my Ajax monitor application.

**[EDIT]**

LOL! Even I couldn't of begun to answer this vague question.

Sorry was in a rush when asking question.

Context:

The `ajaxMonitor` program wraps the JQuery.ajax function. It is a plug-in. This Monitor will be used to monitor ajax communications between a client and server. The first thing that will occurr is a jsonp request will be sent to a server to verify that communications work between the client and a known good, reliable server (google, msn, yahoo, or govt.). This way if the first ajax request errors. Then there is a problem not normally applicable to the server-side.

I hope this will clarify my question better.

Comment: Wow, ok, yes... that makes a lot more sense all of the sudden :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Revising answer after the question got updated:

I'm not sure what kind of server would be offering a JSON response you could just use.. I'm guessing it'd have to be some kind of free webservice-over-json thing. How about the alternative of placing a static JSON file somewhere in an Amazon cloud, to serve as your baseline for testing? Amazon S3 is highly reliable, and since the content of the JSON is mostly irrelevant, would this suit your needs?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to do, but you should be able to just set up a file extension mapping so that any "*.json" file is served up with the "application/json" Content-Type. Any web server can be set up to do this, the exact steps depend on which one you want to use.